# Windows File Explorer Left Side Navigation Zoomed In

Tags: windows-explorer

The left side navigation pane for Windows File Explorer is zoomed in. How can I get the zoom level to the default size? I am using Windows 11.

Restarting the computer will set the zoom level to default.

Zoom Size

[image: Zoom Level]

Default Zoom Size

[image: Default Zoom Size]

Comment: Do you perhaps have a multiple monitor setup with mixed scaling levels?

Comment: @DanielB, yes, I have 2 monitors, the 4K monitor is at 150% and the 1080p monitor is at 100% scaling. I only keep the File Explorer on the 1080p monitor, I do not move it to the other monitor.

Comment: Do try moving it anyway, back and forth. Also, when the error occurs, instead of rebooting, try just logging out and logging back in. If either of those fixes it, it’s because Windows sucks at DPI scaling.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the font size was changed, but you might be able to
[Restore File Explorer To Default Settings](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-restore-file-explorer-to-default-settings-in-windows-10-11/):

- Open Folder Options in Explorer :

  - In Windows 11, click the three dots in the toolbar and select Options
  - In Windows 10, click the File menu and select
    "Change folder and search options"
- In Folder Options, General tab, click the button of "Restore Defaults"
- Do the same for the View and Search tabs
  (some of this might be an over-kill, but only testing
  will tell)
- Click the buttons of Apply and OK.

Answer (score 0):

Go to (open) Windows Explorer.

In the ribbon, 3 dots   (...)

Select Folder Options.

Now in View, check (select) the option to Decrease Space between items.

You can also in the General Options dialogue box restore Explorer Defaults.   Try that especially if you made numerous changes to Windows Explorer.

Now restart Windows Explorer - indeed maybe even restart the computer and see if now Explorer is working normally. It is here.

If the above does not work, try running DISM / SFC

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: I already have this option checked. Restarting the computer does get the zoom level back to default. The problem is I am not sure what I am hitting to get the zoom level increased. It also doesn't happen for every folder.

Answer (score 0):

"I am not sure what I am hitting to get the zoom level increased." Many apps use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-*Mouse Scroll Wheel* to change zoom ratio. In the *right* pane of (*Windows 10*) Explorer, both in **some folder types** (e.g., *This PC*, *Desktop*, *Videos*) it both changes magnification and view type (detail, icons, *larger* icons, **yet larger** icons...). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>*n*</kbd> (where *n* is a number, 1 through 8) also selects the *right* pane view type. Though I cannot test on Windows 11 Explorer, see if that has the same effect on the left pane.

Also note that, *after* pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, Explorer shows keyboard shortcuts.

[image: Alt Keyboard Shortcuts]

It might be that on occasion <kbd>Alt</kbd> is hit, and then, another key changes zoom.

Comment: These actions don't seem to work in Windows 11 Explorer.

Comment: @harrymc, Thanks! This confirms my thoughts about staying with 10 until the bitter end.

Comment: You can use third-party apps to approximate Windows 10 very nearly. Some modern computers don't support Windows 10 any more.

Comment: Ah, but the old and new both support Linux - and as my current Windows 10 PC's are dual-boot, I can drop the old OS when security updates cease.

Comment: Not only security updates - I can't for example install Windows 10 on my current computer's hardware. That's if you're planning on getting a new computer.